# How can I calculate a distinct count of a dimension in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have Googled this and searched the Tableau forums but I'm coming up empty. How can I calculate a distinct count of City Names using Tableau?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Is it not:

1. Create Calculated Field Analysis->Create Calulatated Field
2. Name it and enter the below formula

   ```
   COUNTD([City Name])
   ```
3. Then pull that into your measures?

This should give you your total count. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Not available on my string field... "Unknown function COUNTD called."

Comment: Creating a calc Field may not be necessary.  In the given view, the countD of city per city will be obviously one.  Else for a country --> drag both to rows.  Right click city and then --> measure--> Count Distinct.

Answer (score 0):

**Another easy way to tackle this problem:**

"we need two information as city name and city name (Count Distinct)"

1.To get city name Select [city name] and drag it to row shelf.

2.Again Drag city name into row shelf and Right click on city name in row shelf and Go into measures and select Count Distinct.

Describe in the below link about how to do count Distinct of city name
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpnrj.png